# Fedora 16 continuously rebooting after install

Tags: linux, fedora

I just installed Fedora 16 x86 64-bit on my Samsung Laptop (NP300 Series). The installation seemed to have worked fine but after the first reboot, it seems that the OS keeps rebooting repeatedly.

Anyone that had the same issue? Any pointers on what can be done to prevent this and boot into the OS?

Comment: Does it reboot predictably? About how long after start up? Does it display anything when it reboots? Do any particular things tend to make it reboot.

Comment: After the bios setup screen that displays the manufacturer logo, it would seem that the system boots into Fedora for just a fraction of a second and then reboots. Nothing is displayed - just that the LCD keeps going on and off making it seem that the system is continuously rebooting since the manufacturer logo doesn't show upon system restart. I don't think there's anything in particular that makes it reboot. I tried installing Ubuntu & Windows 7, both work fine except for Fedora.